# Interpreting TensorFlow Timeline profile

Tags: tensorflow

I wrote a TensorFlow code and generated the timeline plot using `tensorflow.python.client.timeline` . However I am not clear about how to interpret the timeline and understand the bottlenecks in the code. At the moment I have just written a basic CPU based data augmentation code but some help about how to interpret the plot would be very helpful.

TensorFlow Version used : v1.1 (Compiled from sources)

My code is as follows :

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    from tensorflow.python.client import timeline
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    def coloraugment(image):
        output = tf.image.random_brightness(image, max_delta=100./255.)
        output = tf.clip_by_value(output, 0.0, 1.0)
        output = tf.image.random_saturation(output, lower=0.2, upper=2)
        output = tf.clip_by_value(output, 0.0, 1.0)
        output = tf.image.random_contrast(output, lower=0.2, upper=2)
        output = tf.clip_by_value(output, 0.0, 1.0)
        return output


    def augmentbody(image, sz):

        for i in range(5):
            if i == 0:
                cropped = tf.random_crop(value=image, size=sz)
                croppedflipped = tf.image.flip_left_right(cropped)
                out = tf.stack([cropped, croppedflipped], axis=0)
            else:
                cropimg = tf.random_crop(value=image, size=sz)
                augcolor = coloraugment(cropimg)
                augflipped = tf.image.flip_left_right(augcolor)
                coll = tf.stack([augcolor, augflipped], axis=0)
                out = tf.concat([coll, out], axis=0)

        out = tf.random_shuffle(out)
        return out


    def aspect1(aspectratio):
        jit_scope = tf.contrib.compiler.jit.experimental_jit_scope
        with jit_scope():
            newheight = tf.constant(256, dtype=tf.float32)
            newwidth = tf.divide(newheight, aspectratio)
            newsize = tf.stack([newheight, newwidth], axis=0)
            newsize = tf.cast(newsize, dtype=tf.int32)
        return newsize


    def aspect2(aspectratio):
        jit_scope = tf.contrib.compiler.jit.experimental_jit_scope
        with jit_scope():
            newwidth = tf.constant(256, dtype=tf.float32)
            newheight = tf.multiply(newwidth, aspectratio)
            newsize = tf.stack([newheight, newwidth], axis=0)
            newsize = tf.cast(newsize, dtype=tf.int32)
        return newsize


    def resize_image(image):
        imageshape = tf.shape(image)
        imageheight = tf.cast(tf.gather(imageshape, tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32)),
                              dtype=tf.float32)
        imagewidth = tf.cast(tf.gather(imageshape, tf.constant(1, dtype=tf.int32)),
                             dtype=tf.float32)

        aspectratio = tf.divide(imageheight, imagewidth)
        newsize = tf.cond(tf.less_equal(imageheight, imagewidth),
                          lambda: aspect1(aspectratio),
                          lambda: aspect2(aspectratio))
        image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, dtype=tf.float32)
        image = tf.image.resize_images(image, newsize)
        return image

    def readimage(input_queue):
        reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
        key, value = reader.read(input_queue)
        image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(value)
        image = resize_image(image)
        return image
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        jit_scope = tf.contrib.compiler.jit.experimental_jit_scope
        with jit_scope():
            queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["Lena.jpg"])
            image = readimage(queue)
            augmented = augmentbody(image, [221,221,3])
            init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
            config = tf.ConfigProto()
            config.graph_options.optimizer_options.global_jit_level = tf.OptimizerOptions.ON_1
            with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
                run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
                run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
                coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
                threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
                sess.run(init_op)
                [tense] = sess.run([augmented], options=run_options, run_metadata=run_metadata)
                coord.request_stop()
                coord.join(threads)
                tl = timeline.Timeline(run_metadata.step_stats)
                ctf = tl.generate_chrome_trace_format()
                with open('timeline.json', 'w') as f:
                    f.write(ctf)

        print("The tensor size is {}".format(tense.shape))
        numcols = tense.shape[0]/2
        for i in range(tense.shape[0]):
            plt.subplot(2,numcols,i+1)
            plt.imshow(tense[i, :, :, :])

        plt.show()
        plt.close()
```

My main questions are as follows :

1. How do I interpret this plot ? (If a closer look at the timeline is required, you can find it [here](https://codeshare.io/a3Dvjg))
2. How do I understand the overhead of XLA compiler and what does _XLA_LAUNCH mean in the plot ?
3. How do I determine the sequence of operations taking place ?
4. What is denoted by different pids in the plot ?

[image: Timeline plot generated using TensorFlow]

Comment: Could you take a look at this bit of [XLA documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/jit#step_1_prepare_sample_script)? It includes instructions for "un-packing" the compiled _XlaLaunch kernels. It looks like all of your ops are running on the GPU, not the CPU (PID is just "process ID"; the interesting bit is "gpu:0" vs. "cpu:0" indicating the device the ops are running on).